# implicit declaration of function CC_MD5 is invalid in C99 error in this line please give me solutions

Tags: iphone

```
float degress = degrees(acos((metersXA * metersXA + metersXB * metersXB - metersAC * metersAC) / (2 * metersXA* metersXB)));
```

Comment: There is no reference to "CC_MD5" in the line you've posted.

Comment: You will need to post more of the code and more background info.

Comment: You probably forgot to `#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>`

Answer (score 10):

To be able to safely use  a function its return type and number of arguments need to be known at compile time. To make it known you have to declare it.

Since it is not YOUR function, it wouldn't make sense for you to declare it though SO
**you have to import the header containing the declaration**

`#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>`

Comment: Note: you'll also have to link against the CommonCrypto framework!